# How to change parent size in Windows forms by its child?

Tags: c#, winforms, size, parent

In my parent Form I have this command where I add a child form into my main form:

```
 AddChildForm(new Form2());
```

And in my Form2 I have a check box, and every time the check box is checked I have to change my Main form size, but I can't get to this work, only create a new form, like this:

```
Form1 main = new Form1();
main.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(482, 370);
main.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: I would suggest that you don't want Form2 to change Form1, rather you want Form2 to inform Form1 that it needs to change.  Look into anonymous event handlers. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366768.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want a new `Form1` don't create it.

You probably need a **reference** to the real main form. This should be set at some time during or after opening it, but since all you show us is are 4 out of context lines we can't tell for sure..

And since we don't see the `AddChildForm` code it is even harder to guess.

However, chances are that you should pass a reference from the **opening** form to the **opened** form like this:

```
AddChildForm(new Form2(this));  //  <--- pass in reference to the opening form!
```

And store it there like this:

```
Form1 mainForm = null;

public Form2(Form1 form1)   // here we receive the main form reference
{
    InitializeComponent();
    mainForm = form1;      // here we store it in a class level variable
    //..
}
```

Now you can set the other forms Size:

```
mainForm.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(482, 370);
```

Of course you should keep a reference to the form you are opening in the main form as well, if you will need it.  For this use something like this instead:

```
Form2 form2 = new Form2(this);
..

AddChildForm( form2);
```